# Leaving the US with a foreign passport and entering with a US passport

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

I will be traveling to Europe and Asia with my Hong Kong passport (tickets were booked with my previous legal name) and coming back with my US passport (I will be booking the ticket with my Hong Kong passport, since it has my previous legal name).

Will I get into trouble with US immigration when coming back? Since the US doesn't check passports going out of the country, how do they know who went out? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @JonathanReez that's not a duplicate.  In the other case, the traveler is asking about leaving the US passport behind altogether and showing the foreign passport on return to the US.  In this case, the traveler plans to take the US passport and show it on return.

Comment: You'll probably get some questions about it from the border agent upon your return, since your U.S. passport won't have the proper stamps for where ever you're coming back from, so make sure you have a proper answer prepared.  This same thing happened to a coworker of mine, though he unintentionally used two different passports.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I would say the probability is very low.  I've never had a US border officer look for passport stamps from other jurisdictions.  I'm sure it happens, but it seems to be the exception rather than the rule.  If they do ask, though, the "proper answer" is of course "I used my other passport, which you're welcome to see of you want."

Comment: @phoog It's probably more likely these days, with the current administration's attitude towards... "border issues".  My coworker had been using his passports interchangeably for decades without so much as a question before his incident earlier this year.  Either way, to be forewarned is to be forearmed.

Comment: @Hopeless N00b but in this case, as in mine, one of the passports is a US passport.  That makes a huge difference when one is entering the US.

Comment: @phoog yeah I also had a question about it. If they check my US passport, they wouldn't be able to find any stamps. Not sure if U.S log outbound flight and inbound flight just to see where I go. I will update after my trip.

Comment: The US has stamped my US passport every time I've entered by air.  No passport inspector has ever looked more than briefly at the stamps in any of my passports, but I've never been to Hong Kong (nor anywhere else in Asia aside from Turkey).  I'm surprised at how many people worry about border guards reconciling stamps at routine border crossings given that it almost never happens.

Answer (score 15):

It does not matter.  I've done this several times.  There's a law that requires US citizens to "bear" a valid US passport when leaving and entering the US, but [there's no penalty for violating the law](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85389/what-is-the-penalty-for-us-citizens-entering-leaving-the-us-on-a-foreign-passpor), and in any case *using* a non-US passport is not forbidden.

Comment: Agreed, I always use my European passport in Europe, and US Passport in the states.

Comment: The one requirement OP hasn't mentioned is the having a proof of name change since ticket and Passport names are different.

Comment: @Johns-305 it seems to me that two current photographic (probably biometric) identity documents from different jurisdictions showing different names ought to be sufficient.

Comment: @phoog Ehhh.....grey area.  CBP specifically says "proof of your name progression" implying the start and end points may not suffice on their own.  https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1209/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNTEyNTcwMDQ4L3NpZC9YVjZOWnd6bg%3D%3D

Comment: @Johns-305 what if there's no "progression" or change, but the person simply has two different names because of conflicting name laws?  Anyway,  CBP does not matter here.  Once the traveler arrives in the US he just shows the US passport. It doesn't matter what name the ticket is in, nor the foreign passport.  The question is checking in for the return flight, which the airline controls.

Comment: @phoog Well....'previous' implies 'progression'.  Don't HK Passport have both English and Cantonese/Chinese names?  The CBP Officer may wonder how you got there without being listed on any incoming manifests.

Comment: @Johns-305 the US passport is in the current name, and ought to be on the manifest because the traveler will have to show it in order to check in for the flight.

Comment: @phoog "will be booking the ticket with my Hong Kong passport, since it has my previous legal name"

Comment: The only (minor?) mystery I see with this involves getting on the return flight to the US. If the ticket is booked in the HKSAR passport's name that passport will need to be used to identify the OP to the airline as the ticket holder but won't permit US entry. The US passport certainly permits entry, but I don't see a way to construct an APIS message with a travel document with a name different than the ticket holder's. I assume the airline may have some way to square that circle (maybe just update the name for APIS?) but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Johns-305 sure, but there's no way this is the first person who's had this problem.  There must be a provision for someone to board a flight to the US with a US passport where the name does not match that on the ticket.  APIS has a pointer to the PNR.  Surely name mismatches are common enough.

Answer (score 11):

One point of confusion here is that *leaving* one country is not the same as *entering* the next country. We have questions on this site (for example [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)) about traveling between two countries using two passports, where you want to use one passport for one country and another for the other country. You should enter and leave each particular country with the same passport, so you should leave country A with the passport you entered country A with, but you can then enter country B with a different passport. In other words, on a single flight, you can "use" two different passports for the two ends of the flight. So "entering" the destination using your HKSAR passport does not imply that you "left" the US with that passport.

Of course, with the US, there are no exit checks (technically CBP could conduct random checks of departing passengers, but it is extremely rare and I have never seen it happen). In this case, you "leave" the US without needing to do anything. Although US law technically requires a US citizen to "enter" and "leave" the US with a US passport (with some exceptions for children and people with certain border crossing cards), when there are no exit checks, you vacuously satisfy the requirement to "leave" using a US passport without doing anything (technically the law says "bear" a US passport, which could mean just having it in your possession).

Comment: Just to add airlines don't enforce borders but can be worried to get back (for free) someone cannot enter destination and can asks to see your passport, in those cases show your destination passaport to the airline crew.

Comment: Apparently there are certain flights where CBP exit checks are common, though overall they are indeed rare.  @jean airlines *may* enforce documentation requirements.  One time I tried to check in to an international departure from the US at an automated kiosk with my foreign passport, and the kiosk wouldn't let me do so without scanning a visa or green card.  That was with an airline I don't often use, but I've never had that problem with the airlines I usually use.  Certainly, airlines submit document data to CBP to reconcile departures with entry records.

Comment: @phoog that's is odd and sound like "We need to know if you overstayed, in this case instead of letting you to leave we are deporting you". My comment was unclear, I stated that for cases where your origin passport needs a visa but your destination passport don't

Comment: @jean a US visa does not determine whether someone has overstayed; the place to look for that is the I-94, which is retrieved using the passport number.

Comment: @phoog So a good question is why they want to see your visa/greencard? To block any try to re-enter? and this is really odd if the subject is carrying a usa passport anyway

Comment: @Jean it was for a round trip originating in the US, so I guess they wanted to be sure I would be admissible on return.  When they were asking for the visa or green card they didn't yet know I had a US passport, of course.