# Dual USA and UK travelling to USA for funeral - expired USA passport

Tags: usa, uk, passports, dual-nationality

I’m travelling to the USA on Monday for a sudden and unplanned funeral. I have just realised that my USA Passport is expired- only just (June 15 2019).
I do have my UK Passport which is in date and valid but I am unsure of what might happen if I travel into USA on UK. I ca obviously arrange to fill an ESTA and I also have a valid USA Driving license.
What do you recommend? Should I just chance it and travel in as a UK citizen?

Comment: I would recommend you travel on your UK Passport. There’s no penalty for doing so. As an American citizen you cannot be denied entry into the USA.  Worst that happens is you get a short lecture. That said, you can get an emergency passport in one day but it’s the weekend so not possible.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111244/can-i-return-to-america-if-i-used-my-philippine-passport-although-i-am-an-americ/111257#111257

Comment: @user56513 Doesn't the expired American passport constitute proof of American citizenship for entering the country? So leave the UK with the UK passport, enter the US with the expired US passport, possible lecture for expired passport.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes it is. So he should definitely carry it along for ease of admission if asked. The probability of a UK citizen being stopped is very very low anyway such that it's unlikely it will be needed.