# As a dual citizen, my US passport will expire one day after traveling to the US. Will this work?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, dual-nationality, regulations, passport-renewals

As a dual citizen, my US passport will expire one day after traveling to the US (May 4th). I will be staying for one week, flying back to Europe afterwards (where I am a resident). Can I enter with my US passport, and leave with my valid EU passport? I'm flying with Icelandair.

Also, in this case I shouldn't try to get an ESTA for my EU passport, right?

PS. When trying to use an emergency procedure to renew my US passport, I am not getting any replies from the US consulate.

Comment: If you are a US citizen you must enter under your US passport and can stay indefinitely. There is no need for ESTA. You can get an expedited renewal for your passports once in the US if time permits.

Comment: Related question says you only have to ‘bear’ your US passport, you don’t have to use it to enter the US https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135346/dual-citizen-exited-the-us-on-italian-passport-recently

Comment: Could I get into trouble when leaving the US again with my EU passport? For example, will their system show that I do not have an ESTA, or that I did not enter the country with this passport?

Comment: @Robin: There is no border control when leaving the US. According to the letter of the law, as a citizen you're required to "bear" a valid US passport when you leave the question, but there's no effective enforcement (and no punishment is defined if you fail to follow that rule anyway).

Comment: Thank you.

I have read reports of people being spot-checked by security and/or the airline refusing to let you on board while scanning the non-US passport. What is everyone's opinion on the chances of this happening?

Comment: It’s happened to me (especially back when there were still paper I94s) that while checking in with a non-US passport and no I94 (as I had entered with my US passport) they asked about it. Just show your US passport if they ask, but they shouldn’t care more than that, and the validity should be irrelevant, they’ll only care about the validity of the passport you’ll use to enter the destination country.

Comment: @Traveller the practical implication of the law I'd that the US passport must be shown to the passport inspector on entry, but one can *leave* without a valid US passport with relative ease and impunity because of the lack of government-operated exit checks.

Comment: You can renew your passport while in the US if you are near a [passport agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies.html).

Comment: @jcaron US or foreign airline?  I think US airlines pay closer attention to these things.  I've never been asked for an I-94 flying to Europe on European airlines with a European passport, but flying to Africa on a US airline I used my US passport because the checkin kiosk had required my wife to scan her US visa.

Comment: May 4 is two weeks away; an expedited passport renewal from abroad is faster than that. It's disconcerting that the US consulate isn't replying to you. What emergency procedure are you following?

Comment: @krubo: the part where it tells you to send them an e-mail on here: https://nl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/emergency-passports/

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out!! My plan is to continue pursuing an emergency passport. In case this fails, my back up plan is to enter the US with my US passport and leave with my EU passport (without any ESTA).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual Citizen. Exited the US on Italian passport recently](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135346/dual-citizen-exited-the-us-on-italian-passport-recently)

Comment: @Robin I don't know how serious the US embassy will think your emergency is. Nonetheless, they ought to reply to you promptly. Maybe they're understaffed. You could try calling their number for US citizen emergencies (mouseover the US Citizen Services on their website) to at least find out their advice.

Comment: I hope your flight is not delayed

Comment: If you can prove you are a US citizen, you _must_ be admitted. If your passport is expired, expect hassle, but you will be admitted. (I believe the law providing a fine is repealed.) With one day remaining, you will be admitted without issue (unless you are bringing contraband, etc.). You do not have to present a US passport to leave. Get the passport renewed when you return to your foreign residence, on a non-emergency basis.

Comment: So while trying to check in today with Icelandair (using my US Passport), I only managed to check in until Reykjavik, but not from Reykjavik to the US. After calling them, they stated that because my passport is not valid on the return leg, the check-in failed. They told me to try to explain it at the airport counter, in the hope that I would get a boarding pass there.

What do you think my chances are?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As a US Citizen - which is what gives you the right to a US Passport, you can stay indefinitely in the US. You are not even required to have a US passport, although that makes it easier to enter the United States. Your passport is valid the day you arrive, so there should not be any problem. You could be coming back to renew your passport as I suggest you do, to make it easier to get back in. Should you not have enough time to do so, you can always have it renewed at a US embassy abroad.

Given that you are a US citizen, you are also not eligible for an ESTA. Leaving on any passport is not an issue in the US because the US does not do exit immigration. Airlines do share data telling who is leaving the US but that is not the same as exit immigration.

Given your schedule seems a little tight, just procede normally. Enter the US on your still-valid US passport then fly out and enter the EU with your EU passport. From there you will have more time to renew your US passport which you can do without the emergency procedure. Just make sure you have all the documentation with you when you leave the US. The US government has all the relevant information on [their website here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/renew-by-mail.html).

Comment: There are several reports on this site of US dual citizens being granted ESTA authorization after disclosing on their applications that they are US citizens.  But ESTA authorization isn't needed here because the traveler arrives while the US passport is still valid.

Answer (score 16):

1. As a US citizen you cannot be denied entry into the US, regardless whether you have a passport or not or whether it's valid
2. Entering without a valid passport can be pain. The immigration officer will need to let you in eventually but they can make it painful process.
3. Since your passport is valid, you are fine either way. They may grunt at you for a while, but you can just ignore that and say "yes officer" repeatedly.
4. The US has no exit controls, you don't need a US passport to leave the country.
5. Don't use ESTA when dealing with US immigration, use your US passport, expired or not.

Comment: Because of the law requiring US citizens to "bear" a valid US passport on departure, a CBP officer could prevent OP from boarding if the lack of a valid US passport were discovered in a spot check.  Spot checks are pretty uncommon on most routes, however.  I also believe US airlines pay more attention to the immigration status of departing passengers than do European airlines.

Comment: @phoog, good luck trying to board a Eurpean plane without valid passport. You will not even reach the gates.

Comment: @akostadinov we're talking about a US citizen who is also a citizen of another country and shows their valid non-US passport when checking in for a flight departing the US.

Comment: @akostadinov No passport needed at all (as a European citizen). ID card is sufficient. You may need a passport to leave the US but that's unrelated to any “European plane”.

Comment: @akostadinov You can in the UK. Driving licences are valid for domestic flights.

Answer (score 0):

No US citizen should ever get ESTA.  That is for people who do not have *any* US citizenship.

Citizens should enter their own country with their own country's passport.  Therefore you should enter the US with a US passport and enter the EU with an EU country's passport.

Airlines are concerned with the possibility of you arriving at a country *and then being refused entry*.  They pay fines and penalties if that happens, because airlines are expected to pre-check your paperwork. **When they see you are a citizen of the destination country, that puts them at ease** because you cannot be refused entry if you are a citizen.

America doesn't have exit controls so they don't care how you leave. When boarding a flight to the EU, show your EU passport.