# Trying to cross into Tijuana by foot without a passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, borders, mexico

Assuming I have an essential travel need, I would like to know about crossing into tijuana with a receipt + paperwork from the post office that will work as a temporary passport. When you apply for a passport at the post office do they give you something that will serve as a temporary passport? Just was wondering what they give you when you apply for a passport when you never have had one. I am a US citizen.

Comment: Not sure what your travel need is, but if you have a life-or-death emergency, you can still get an [expedited at agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/processing-times.html) passport within 3 days. "Life-or-death emergencies are serious illnesses, injuries, or deaths in your immediate family (parent, legal guardian, child, spouse, sibling, and grandparent) that require you to travel outside the United States within 72 hours (3 business days)."

Comment: @stackoverblown That is quite the assumption. Why shouldn't a relative of his live or work in Mexico because their last name isn't latino? Maybe the relative always only recently moved there. Maybe the relative always visited the OP in the states. Maybe the relative was there on a temporary visit and had a sudden medical emergency. I thought it appropriate not to make assumptions about his circumstances and only present the available options. Even if it doesn't apply to the OP, it might apply to a future reader with the same question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Passports are issued by the US Department of State, not the US Postal Service. When you file a passport application at a US Post Office, the USPS will issue a receipt for your money payment...but they don't give you a "temporary passport."  What you'll get is a *receipt*, which is not the same as a passport, and no immigration officer from any country will consider it as a valid travel document. The Department of State will later mail your new passport to you.

I'm unfamiliar with the US > Mexico pedestrian crossing at San Ysidro, but I've many times entered Mexico by vehicle without having Mexican Immigration pay any attention to me at all. Because the US has no exit immigration checks, you may be able to walk right across the border into Mexico without issue, although Mexican law may require you to complete an FMM (*forma migratoria múltiple*) which in practice is rather like a visa or tourist card.

On the other hand, US citizens are required by federal law to enter the US while bearing a US passport. (US citizens must exit the US while bearing a US passport too, but because there are no US exit checks for crossings by land, they may not notice in this case.) While US Customs and Border Protection must admit you to the US even if you have no passport, they will only do so after they're satisfied that you are in fact a US citizen.

Presenting yourself for entry into the US, saying you're a citizen but not carrying a US passport, sets yourself up for a protracted and unpleasant experience while they try to determine your citizenship and identity. At the very least, you will be significantly delayed and the CBP officers will be quite displeased. If they think you're not a US citizen, you could be refused entry back into the US.

Comment: If OP is from Michigan, Minnesota, New York, Vermont or Washington they can also use an Enhanced drivers license instead.

Comment: I seem to recall that Mexico was planning to eventually check everyone at the border, rather than at the inland checkpoints. I don't recall when this was supposed to be in effect, but I don't think it is now.

Comment: Mexican law does require an FMM but there is no fee for less than seven days visit.  When I entered through Nuevo Laredo a couple years ago (more than once), no one bothered to tell me to go to the office for the paperwork, much less to described the convoluted route to get to the place.

Comment: 8 USC 1185 actually says that US citizens must "bear" a valid US passport, not that they must _use_ it, although that's only really relevant for departures, and in any event it doesn't much matter in these circumstances.  CBP is working on a fee for WHTI-noncompliant US citizens, which will probably make things somewhat smoother in case like this, provided the traveler can pay.

Comment: Even if the Mexican authorities don't pay attention to you at the border, you may still be entering Mexico illegally (or continuing too far into Mexico without an FMM), which could potentially pose a problem should they pay attention to you later.

Comment: I believe you all. I am not crossing right now. I just hate this covid. It will be months before a passport is issued. Thank you all.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the correction. I amended the answer.

Comment: An interesting point for this is that while you do legally have to "bear" a US passport, there are explicitly no actual penalties for not doing so. You may be delayed, and you may have trouble proving that you are allowed entry, but you cant be prosecuted etc under this statute (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157373/how-to-lawfully-leave-united-states-without-a-united-states-passport-for-united)

Comment: @BeB00 Now I'm wondering if there's been any pro-immigration protests where the (US citizen) protestors entered Mexico legally, disposed of their passports while in Mexico, then set about trying to re-enter the United States illegally.

Comment: @nick012000 A US citizen, who did not have his/her citizenship revoked, can enter the USA illegally?

Comment: @stackoverblown See BeB00's comment immediately above mine - you're required to have a passport on you during re-entry, but there's no criminal penalty for not doing so.

Comment: @nick012000 My point is if a US citizen, in good standing, decides to swim across Rio Grande from Mexico and enters the US that way. What is the authority going to charge him/her with?

Comment: @stackoverblown Probably nothing, but a few hundred of them at once might be able to clog up a border checkpoint pretty badly.

Comment: @stackoverblown Customs offenses. It's a federal crime to enter the US without submitting to customs inspection.

Comment: @nick012000: You're required to have your passport when you enter, but I don't think it counts as "re-enter[ing] the United States illegally" if you don't. (By analogy: in many jurisdictions, you're not allowed to bring a gun into a school. But if you do so, your crime isn't "entering the school illegally", it's "bringing a gun into the school". Likewise, if you're a U.S. citizen entering the U.S. without your passport, it's not "entering the U.S. illegally", it's "not bearing a passport while entering the U.S.")

Comment: Note that you don't ever want to join the 'non-US' queue getting back from TJ. You also don't want to ever take a car unless you've a day to spend queueing. Having walked over once with my American friends; on returning they arranged we should meet them at a bar near where we had parked, SanDiego side… which we did, a mere 6 hours later, having spent the intermediate time queuing with perfectly valid non-US documents + visa.

Comment: A followup to my [earlier comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159481/trying-to-cross-into-tijuana-by-foot-without-a-passport#comment400177_159482): A look at the [regulatory agendas](https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaHistory) for the last few years shows that "Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative (WHTI)--Noncompliant Traveler Fee" was abandoned as of Spring 2022 -- it was present until Fall 2021 in the "proposed rule" stage, but then it disappears.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the other good answer, I'll answer specifically for Tijuana.

You say you are crossing by foot into Tijuana - All 3 pedestrian ports of entry into Tijuana from San Diego have passport checks, and you are unlikely to be admitted without a passport.  I have heard of one or two people being successful in talking the border guards into allowing them in anyway, however these were people that had already been in Mexico and had only temporarily crossed back into San Diego for shopping (etc).  I am aware of far more people who have been denied entry due to no passport.

Visitors to Mexico from the US (and other non-Visa countries) are typically required to have an FMM (visitor/tourism permit) which is obtained at the border, and requires presenting a passport to obtain the FMM, so this would make it difficult anyway.

As noted in the other answer, entering by vehicle usually attracts little attention and no stop, so it is possible to enter Mexico by vehicle without a passport, but I would comment that this isn't necessarily legal, even though it is possible, and if you are stopped by INM (immigration) while in Mexico and you can't provide your FMM or passport you will likely be deported.

Comment: Does a US citizen entering by foot in Tijuana obtain an FMM from the passport inspector?  Or is it necessary to obtain it beforehand and present it to the passport inspector?  If so, where does one get it from?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old discussion but I just spoke with a relative who walked across for dental work at Los Palomas, which is south of Columbus New Mexico. No passport. He did go prepared though. First, he called the main CBP office in El Paso. It was explained to him that for an American Citizen with sufficient identification the border guards must allow you back in.

In my relative's example, he carried a photocopy of his original birth certificate and of course his New Mexico driver license. The CBP guard when he crossed back with obvious swollen mouth and some bleeding gums from dental work still hassled him. But he simply said clearly and politely as his mouth situation permitted that he knew the law, he'd shown proof of American birth and photo ID and he could not be refused.

Took maybe two minutes in that case, but back right back into the USA he walked.

Comment: I suppose if it only took a couple of minutes then the hassle was not that severe -- is that the case?