# Do I need a passport to fly to Mexico if I was born in Mexico

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Do I need a passport when flying into Mexico from CA if I was born in Mexico?
Is my resident alien card and birth certificate sufficient?

Comment: You can also walk across the border from El Paso to Ciudad Juarez. A passport is technically needed to cross there, but I have found that it is frequently not enforced when crossing on foot *from the USA to Mexico*, and once you are in Mexico, well, your birth certificate will prove that you are Mexican if anyone wants to ask. In fact, it might be enough to get you in even if someone tried to give you trouble at the border crossing: I don't think that a Mexican citizen—which anyone born in Mexico is—can be legally barred from returning to Mexico.

Comment: Though they might fine you as the USA has contemplated doing to their own citizens who cross back without a passport—which by the by shows how easy it can be to cross from the US to Mexico without one.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Note that it would [require an act of Congress](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/86059/39667) for the US government to actually charge such fines. The law as it currently stands says that doing so is illegal, but specifies no penalty.