# Can dual US/UK citizen travel with only UK passport and ESTA?

Tags: usa, uk, paperwork, esta, dual-nationality

I have a 20-year-old daughter, born in the US to military British parents. She has dual nationality / both birth certificates.

Her US passport is expired and Social Security number misplaced. She needs to travel to the USA as soon as possible.

Can she travel on her British passport with an ESTA? She can't wait for 8 weeks to get new Social Security number, and then three more weeks for a new US passport.

Will she be okay with her British passport with an ESTA?

Comment: "Authorization via ESTA does not determine whether a traveler is admissible to the United States. U.S. Customs and Border Protection officers determine admissibility upon travelers’ arrival." from https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta so I suggest you discuss your situation with US consulate or embassy.

Comment: Provided she us a US Citizen, she cannot be denied entry to the US. Technically, if she somehow reached immigration or a land border, she will be allowed the enter the country but of course after a 'friendly' immigration Q&A + lecture + advice etc.

Comment: She can't get a new social security number.  She can only get a new card with the same number on it.  As far as I remember, she doesn't need the card for the application, so if she has a record of the number somewhere, she doesn't need to wait for a new card.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104712/should-people-with-dual-nationality-obtain-and-renew-both-passports

Comment: I have to mention that your daughter is legally obliged to file a tax return for the US, and to pay US takes, for which she would have to supply her SSN.

Comment: I'm surprised you view this as a big problem. I would've just gone with my expired US passport. What are they going to do? Throw me in jail because I didn't renew my passport? Do they really have nothing better to do? Seems like a pretty understandable situation that you're out of the country and haven't gotten around to renewing your passport.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Are you legally obliged to file, or only legally obliged to pay the tax? (The difference being that if you have nothing to pay -- perhaps because the US recognizes that you've paid to another country -- then you wouldn't need to file either.)

Comment: @Mehrdad You're not getting on a flight to the US on an expired US passport

Comment: @Mehrdad In most cases you are obliged to file a tax return if your gross income exceeds a small threshold (about $10,000) *even if all of it was earned abroad and you have never visited the US*. If you want more details our [Personal Finance site](http://money.stackexchange.com) would be a great place to ask.

Comment: @Coke: Ahh, I didn't realize that, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @DJClayworth: Did not know! I thought it was only if you owed taxes. Thanks!

Comment: @Merhdad+ actually money.SX is a good place to look at numerous _existing_ Qs on the filing requirement, the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion, the Foreign Tax Credit, _plus_ the required reports on foreign bank and investment accounts (assets _not_ income) (FBAR and FATCA/form8938).

Comment: Also related: [What is the penalty for dual US citizens who lie on the ESTA form in order to enter under VWP using their second passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86081/19400)

Answer (score 14):

US law says that a US citizen must use a US passport to enter the US. However US law also says that a US citizen cannot be denied entry to the US.

If she makes it to the US border, the most likely scenario is that if they discover that your daughter is a US citizen, she will be given a short lecture from the immigration officer about how she is supposed to have a US passport, before they admit her anyway. That's annoying but nothing more.

Some excellent answers to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/leaving-and-entering-the-us-with-a-foreign-passport/74943#74943) indicate that obtaining an ESTA (which you would need to fly to the US using a VWP country passport) is perfectly possible, even declaring your American citizenship. As an alternative, if you can fly in to Canada or Mexico you could then cross the US border without needing an ESTA.

Comment: I never needed my SSN to renew my passport overseas and It usually arrived a week to two after application

Comment: The DS-82 (passport renewal) and DS-11 (first-time passport) forms do state that "Section 6039E of the Internal Revenue Code (26 U.S.C. 6039E) and 22 U.S.C 2714a(f) require you to provide your Social Security number (SSN), if you have one, when you apply for or renew a U.S. passport." Don't know about enforcement, but it is stated.

Comment: @Hunter you just have to write the social security number in the application.  You don't necessarily need to show the card.

Comment: as @phoog mentioned + you don't even have to attach a copy etc of it.

Comment: Could they refuse to let her *out* of the US again? (as punishment)

Comment: "declaring a US citizenship will make her unable to obtain an ESTA": I wouldn't be so sure.  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74943/19400: "I've gotten an ESTA for my Australian passport. It did ask about being American, I answered yes and it dutifully issued the ESTA."

Comment: @MartinBonner the law says that it is unlawful for a US citizen to enter or leave the US "unless he bears a valid US passport."  So yes, they could in theory prevent her from leaving, but in practice there is no policy or procedure in place to enforce the law on exit.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Edited the answer to take some of them into account.

Comment: I recently renewed my US passport and paid the extra to expedite it and it came back in exactly a week.  If that's not soon enough, I think you can ask for help at US Embassy in the country you're already in, and they can help ensure she enters US without a problem.

Comment: @phoog I know that. The OP did say "number" was misplaced and not "card" was misplaced, so I was going on face value of the original post.

Comment: A US passport is not necessary if entering by air from Canada (NEXUS card also accepted) or by land/sea (passport card, enhanced licence and Trusted Traveller cards also accepted)

Comment: @Coke what do you suppose the possibility is that this person has a NEXUS or other trusted traveler card, an enhanced license, or a passport card?  I suppose that there's no chance whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

She could fly to Canada and enter the US by land. To enter Canada, she can use her US birth certificate, meaning she won't even need to pay for an eTA (if she doesn't have the birth certificate on her, of course she can use her British passport with an eTA too)

The alternative would be applying for an ESTA on her British passport, however she should deny holding dual nationality, or the ESTA may be refused. I also can't guarantee that the system won't find out about her US citizenship.

Comment: She can also fly through Mexico.

Comment: "she'd have to deny holding dual nationality, or the ESTA will be refused": apparently that is incorrect; see https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74943/19400: "I've gotten an ESTA for my Australian passport. It did ask about being American, I answered yes and it dutifully issued the ESTA."

Comment: @phoog Changed the wording - I know cases of ESTAs being refused to dual citizens

Comment: Are you really suggesting lying on an ESTA application? That [seems like a really bad idea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87252/13208) to me.

Comment: @JBentley If not for the fact that OP is a US citizen, meaning the CBP will not penalise them for it

Comment: @Coke Read the answer I linked to (and the question). This is a legal issue, not a border control issue. Also, consider that it can have ramifications for future ESTAs and visas. Yes, it's easy to discount that since she's a US citizen but what if she later revokes for tax or other reasons, or ends up in this same situation again and wanting to use an ESTA? I personally would be wary of advising someone to break the law and create potential future consequences, even if they don't seem to apply right now.

Answer (score 2):

The US government used to have a page [that read, in part](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87252/19400):

> If you have a true emergency, and are unable to obtain a U.S. Passport before your travels, and only have a VWP-eligible passport, then you will have to apply through ESTA using that passport to travel to the U.S. When arriving at the U.S. airport using the foreign passport, you will have to use the non-resident queue.

However, that page [is no longer available](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1096/~/esta---eligible-passport,-country-of-issuance,-citizenship).  The proper course of action for your situation is probably to apply for an [emergency passport](https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/emergency-passports/).