# Dual citizen without a valid US passport

Tags: us-citizens, esta, dual-nationality

I am a dual British/US citizen and hold both passports.  However, my recently renewed US passport has not arrived yet and I leave in 48 hours.  Can I get an ESTA and travel on my British passport?

Comment: Where are you flying from? One person posted here that she was unable to do this at a Canadian airport with preclearance.  But if you're leaving from an airport without preclearance, you might be able to get away with it.

Comment: Also maybe related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86081/what-is-the-penalty-for-dual-us-citizens-who-lie-on-the-esta-form-in-order-to-en

Comment: I am flying from Paris to JFK