# Dual Citizen: CA+USA Travelling to States for non academic school, do I need a student visa?

Tags: visas, usa, us-citizens, dual-nationality, study

I am a dual citizen with CA and the US. I currently reside in CA and have done so for the last 15 yrs (I am 22). I travel on my CA passport. This fall I will be traveling in the states for 89 days for what is considered a "non-academic institution". Do I need a student visa? I have not renewed my American passport in years.

Comment: As a US citizen, you are not eligible for a US visa.

Comment: @Harper that should be a separate question

Comment: @Harper no. US and Canadian citizens are still subject to customs inspection.

Comment: As you're a US citizen, you need a US passport or passport card or enhanced driving licence/state ID. To enter the US by air, you need a US passport

Comment: @LassiUosukainen thanks, asked.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93526/can-a-dual-citizen-disregard-border-controls

Answer (score 37):

If you are a US citizen, regardless of what other citizenships you might have, 
you can enter the US and do whatever you want, for as long as you want, without any kind of visa.  Just renew your US passport and use it to enter the US.

(If you've previously traveled to the US on your Canadian passport, technically that was illegal.  It doesn't have any practical consequences, as far as anyone seems to know, but the US does want you to use your US passport.)

Comment: Assume **X** is a nation in good standing regarding citizen and human rights, probably also a UN member in good standing: *If you are a **X** citizen, regardless of other citizenships you have, you have the right to enter, stay,* do whatever is lawfully allowed *and leave **X** without any kind of visa.* [article 13](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/)

Comment: I think it is a little stronger than the US "wanting" you to use your US passport. Don't they require US citizens to use their US passport? I believe there was a recent high profile case where a British politician renounced their US citizenship for this very reason.

Comment: @Necreaux I think Nate addresses that correctly. Require is probably too strong if there are no practical consequences, but he does use the word 'illegal' correctly. Require implies there are practical consequences.

Comment: @Necreaux high profile cases of US nationality renunciation of which I'm aware, including that of Boris Johnson, are motivated by tax considerations, not passport requirements.

Comment: @Necreaux Also, political opponents will blow things out of proportion. "How can you expect Mr. Johnson to administer the state's education department when he was once clocked doing 26 in a 25... in a SCHOOL ZONE no less. Shame on you, Mr. Johnson! Shame! I for one, would never speed in a school zone like the shameful Mr. Johnson, as I only hire the best personal drivers for my taxpayer funded limousine." So there was probably a bit of eliminating low-hanging fruit for political opponents to grab in the decision too.

Comment: Does Canada have a similar requirement? That is, does the OP need to take both passports along, using the US passport to enter the US and then the CA passport to get back into Canada?

Comment: @1006a: Only for non-US citizens arriving in Canada by air. So the requirement to use a Canadian passport to enter Canada applies to most Canadian dual citizens, but not to the OP. See [Dual Canadian citizens need a valid Canadian passport](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/dual-canadian-citizens.asp) for more information.

Comment: @Necreaux If it was Boris Johnson, it was more serious than that- the US determined he owed them an "outrageous" amount of income tax on the sale of his London home. There may be consequences to establishing tax residency in the US but they are unlikely to be serious for a student unless said student had a lot of income.

Comment: Technically, you don't even need your US passport, or any other, to enter the US if you are a US citizen.  It is highly recommended, though, to quickly prove your citizenship.  In practice, a US driver's license will probably work fine, especially if paired with a US birth certificate, expired passport, and/or other supporting documents.  CBP cannot legally refuse entry to US citizens, no matter how few documents you have (or people whose passports get stolen would be trapped outside the country).  But they can hold you indefinitely until they can determine that you're really a citizen.

Comment: To elaborate on @user3573647's point: these are the [acceptable documents for a US citizen to enter the US](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3618/~/us-citizens---documents-needed-for-entry-into-the-u.s.), and for a Canadian citizen to [re-enter Canada](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html).

Comment: The issue of the legality of using a non-US passport, or other forms of ID, was previously and exhaustively discussed in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/leaving-and-entering-the-us-with-a-foreign-passport.  You may see in particular the citations to the relevant law in Dennis's answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: for a _non-US-national_ establishing tax residency in the US makes a difference, but a US citizen -- even a dual citizen and even one residing abroad -- is _already_ subjected to US income tax _and_ to FBAR and FATCA (asset) reporting which can be even more of a problem; AFAIK US is unique in doing this. If OP doesn't already know about this they should learn; it's probably offtopic for travel.SX but I have seen several good Qs (and As) on it in money.SX.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think you're right- I thought it was as simple as a large deductible but it appears not. Anyway, as you say, off topic here. Expats more so.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need a visa.  Furthermore, you cannot get a visa, except perhaps in a situation where your US citizenship may be in doubt and you need to travel urgently.  Because you have an expired US passport, that exception does not apply to you.

From the [Foreign Affairs Manual](https://fam.state.gov/searchapps/viewer?format=html&query=visa&links=VISA&url=/FAM/09FAM/09FAM020201.html#M202_1_2) of the US State Department, emphasis added:

> 9 FAM 202.1-2 VISA-RELATED ISSUES WITH U.S. CITIZENS
>
> a. Processing Visa Applications for Aliens Who May Have a Claim to U.S. Citizenship:
>
> (1) Nonimmigrant Visa Applicants: **You may not issue a visa to an individual who has been determined to be a U.S. citizen.** However, if a nonimmigrant visa applicant with a possible claim to U.S. citizenship is unable or unwilling to delay travel until he or she has been able to obtain documents to establish that status, as determined by the posts citizenship and passport officer, you may presume that the applicant is an alien pursuing a nonimmigrant visa application. If you find the presumed alien eligible to receive the visa then you may issue the visa.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule everywhere in the world:

- States are mainly interested in your citizenship in the sense of whether you are their citizen or not.
- Their main stand about your other citizenship is *"none of our business"*.
- If you are a citizen of a state, you can enter or leave it any time.

There are many, many, many exceptions, but in practice you can face them rarely.

For the U.S., what matters is whether you are a U.S. citizen or not. If you are not, then it could matter whether you have some other citizenship which makes your case easier. But being a U.S. citizen, it doesn't matter what other citizenships you have.

Comment: I'm not sure how true it is that most countries don't care if you have other citizenships. But, in any case, this doens't seem particularly relevant to the question, even if we generalize it to "I have dual citizenship of countries X and Y; do I need a visa to visit X?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby The essence of the question is that he wants to travel to the US, as a dual US & CA citizen. And the answer is that having US citizenship, his CA citizenship is irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby First, generally a country has access to and operates its databases, registries, and applies its laws on it. In general, its systems don't have access to the systems of other countries, and there is no guarantee about their incompatibility. For example, in Iran, stepping through the border as the wife of an Iranian citizen, also you are counted automatically as an Iranian citizen. A similar automatical citizenship granting is unimaginable in the western countries. The differences between the US & CA aren't so high, but this is the reason of the general case I described here.

Comment: @MorningStar a similar automatic granting of citizenship to wives was formerly common in western countries.  I don't think it's "unthinkable" at all.