# Dual nationality US/UK, wants to return to the US with only a UK passport

Tags: usa, uk, dual-nationality

My daughter was born in England and came to America 32 years ago. She is an American citizen. Two years ago she moved to the UK with a British passport. She now wants to return to the US but doesn't have a US passport. She has never had a US passport.

As a US citizen, can she return using her British passport only?

Comment: She should get a US passport before the trip.  She can do that in the UK.

Comment: I would, as I am sure we all would, love to hear a what happened comment, by either the OP or the daughter.

Answer (score 6):

There are two conflicting laws

1. US citizens must use a US passport to enter the US
2. A US citizen cannot be denied entry

The going legal opinion seems to be that #2 will trump #1, so if your daughter shows up at the border with sufficient proof of citizenship, chances are she will eventually be admitted. See for example https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16654/can-us-citizens-be-denied-entry-to-the-us

However, getting to the border itself will be difficult. No airline will allow her to board with an expired US passport.

The solution is easy enough: she should get a US passport.
If you are in a hurry, do this: https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/emergency-passports/

Comment: She can also fly to Canada or Mexico and cross overland.

Comment: "Chances are": there's actually an old CBP inspector's manual, available in redacted form because of a freedom of information request, in which CBP inspectors are instructed to admit US citizens without passports after explaining that a passport is necessary. The manual notes that the officer is "technically waiving" the passport requirement on behalf of the Secretary of State, but that there is no form required, nor a fee to be paid by the traveler. Policies do change, of course. A web search for `cbp inspector's field manual` currently yields several sources for the document in PDF format.

Comment: "going legal opinion": That seems to imply that opinion might change, but it's not particularly controversial or likely to do so. That's because #2.is a fundamental right inherent in the definition of citizenship, while #1 is just statutory law.

Comment: @CGCampbell: ESTA application requires you to state all your citizenships. It's unlikely that they would give ESTA to a US citizen

Comment: @CGCampbell: but without ESTA no airlines will let her board a US bound flight on a UK passport

Answer (score 4):

No, it is illegal for US citizens to enter or leave the US on other than a US passport. [Leaving and entering the US with a foreign passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/leaving-and-entering-the-us-with-a-foreign-passport)

Comment: It's "unlawful," but it is not a crime to violate that law, and there is [no penalty](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/86059/19400) for doing so.