# Does an American citizen holding a Belgian passport need an ESTA to visit the US?

Tags: us-citizens, esta, dual-nationality

I am a college student living in Belgium coming to visit my parents in the US and I am an American citizen.

Will I need an ESTA?

Comment: If you are a US citizen, you obviously do not need an ESTA, but you will need to prove that you are indeed a citizen. Do you have a US passport?

Comment: In principle US citizens are not even supposed to be *able* to get an ESTA, although there doesn't seem to be any concerted effort to prevent it.

Comment: No, you need a US passport.

Comment: Is there any country in the world where citizens of that country need _anything_ apart from proving their identity/citizenship?

Comment: @Damon: This would make a good question of its own; I wonder if something countries in which you need an exit visa would not require that you present the exit visa when going back in.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Will open that Q then, just for fun and profit :)  -- Presenting exit visa for entry would be quite stupid, methinks. After all, the exit visa is meant to control people who are _motivated_ to leave but whom you can't really afford losing. If you ask for the visa to be shown upon re-entry (... or bad things happen!) you effectively make those who might come back stay away forever. But of course even if it's stupid, that doesn't mean no one will do it, who could tell...

Answer (score 45):

#### No.

However, you will need to travel to the US using your US passport.

From the [Official ESTA Application website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1):

> **Do I need to apply for an ESTA if...?
>
>   I am a U.S. Citizen with dual citizenship in a VWP country?**
>   U.S. Citizens are not required to have an ESTA and **are required to use their U.S. passport to travel to the U.S.**

Answer (score 1):

As a U.S. citizen, you have to travel using your U.S. passport.  That does not mean that you should not be taking your Belgian passport as well since otherwise you might get in trouble for the *return* flight since the airline is not going to like the prospect of letting you into Belgium without any document showing that you are permitted to enter.

Answer (score -1):

If you are a US citizen then no, you will not need an ESTA. US citizens can enter the country without impediment.

You will have to provide evidence of your citizenship. Do you have dual nationality? Or some way to prove you are a US citizen?

If not, you will appear to be Belgian... And will need an ESTA.

Comment: This is against the law (US and international). You are supposed to enter and leave a country you are a citizen of with the documents of this country. This is rarely enforced in Europe but I saw twice it happening (with a US/French citizen ending France with her US passport and a similar one with French/German in Germany)

Comment: @WoJ that's a huge overstatement.  First  there is no international law preventing a dual citizen from entering one country of citizenship with a passport from the other.  It is entirely up to each country to legislate on this, and the UK for example explicitly disclaims such a requirement for its citizens.  Second, while it is against US law for a US citizen to enter the US without a valid US passport, there is no penalty for violating the law.  If a US citizen appears without proper documents, the officer waives the documentary requirement and admits the person.

Comment: '..The officer waives...' - _if_ he can make a convincing case that he is a US citizen. Anyone could say so, you need to have something more convincing. But yes, no passport is needed, it just might take a while longer without a passport.

Comment: @Aganju yes, that's correct, but the officer must investigate the claim to US citizenship beyond the traveler's claims, for example by looking in relevant databases.  A Belgian passport could be enough, for example, if the traveler has previously had a US passport and is therefore in the passport database.

Comment: @WoJ - that's just not true. I used to regularly exit and enter UK and Australia with the wrong passport when I was a teenager (yeah, 'cos that's how annoying teenagers are)

Comment: That said, I am a little surprised at the downvotes - I think everything I wrote is correct here...

Comment: @RoryAlsop: you entered the Australian territory saying " I am Australian but I am entering with a UK passport?" (or the other way round). Of course it happens all the time that people use whatever is most practical for them to enter a country - I am talking about the legal framework. Also see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Comment: @phoog: good to know that the UK explicitly allows their citizens to enter the country with another passport. All the cases I witnessed at borders where when someone was trying to do exactly this. I wish I could update my comment but never mind.

Comment: @phoog Please note that https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1185 mentions that you need a US passport to enter the country as a US citizen. If you don't have any you will still be allowed, you are after all a citizen. This is different from saying "I am a US citizen and I am entering with a French passport". You would then be in the case above "no passport at all" as they will treat you as a US citizen, not a French one.Having a French passport can help to identify you, that's all.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Sorry but I'm pretty sure this is wrong. US citizens cannot apply for ESTAs. The application form asks about other citizenships so the asker would have to either lie (obviously a terrible idea) or admit that they're a US citizen. At that point, surely either the system would refuse to continue the application or the application would be rejected. Perhaps you mean that, without a US passport, the asker will appear to be Belgian to the airline, who will refuse boarding without an ESTA. But then there's not much left in your answer beyond what "I imagine" rather than "I can show."

Comment: US citizens do not need an ESTA @David. My final sentence says that if they are not US, and can't prove they are US then they will obviously be Belgian...and need an ESTA

Comment: @DavidRicherby [The official ESTA help page](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1#) (under "My Country of Issue is not in the ESTA drop down menu, other passport eligibility issues.") contemplates a US citizen entering as a foreigner under the VWP with an ESTA in "a true emergency." We have some [anecdotal experience](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66152/13650) that you can do this and then be denied at US preclearence in Canada though, so it's not really something I'd recommend other than a "anything is better than nothing" situation.