# Two passports, two different names, booked a flight

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, dual-nationality

I have a Colombian passport and I booked a roundtrip to Spain a while ago. This week I became an US citizen and changed my name. So my question is, will I have any trouble coming back to the US since:

1. My two passports have different name
2. I booked my flight with the Colombian passport thinking that I was gonna return using my green card (would I be able to update my flight details to reflect the new US passport and name change?)

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: I do not have the green card anymore as stated by the comments. My concern is that the airline will not let me board coming back to the US because my flight ticket was booked under my Colombian name instead of my US name.

Comment: Now that you're a US citizen,  **do not** show or use the Green Card to check-in for a flight either to or from the US, or to enter the US. Airlines flying from or to the US are required to share passenger info with US Immigration, and you don't want the US to see you using the card. The card is now invalid, should be surrendered, and its use can result in prosecution. Read more [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162538/u-s-and-mexican-citizen-flying-from-u-s-to-mexico/162576#162576). Instead, work with the airline to change the ID details connected to your flights.

Comment: Do you have any documents linking your new name to your old?  I suspect the airline would require you to have two one-way tickets.  It  ought to be possible to use your Colombian passport to prove that you're the person named on the ticket and your US passport to prove that you're a US citizen.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica in all likelihood the green card was already surrendered at the naturalization ceremony.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. The Green Card should have been surrendered, I agree, but the question doesn't address whether it was or remains in the OP's possession. I thought it prudent to address the possibility.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica that it's certainly true.

Comment: I mean _that is certainly true._

Comment: Did you legally change your name, and do you have a document showing that your name was legally changed?

Answer (score 3):

Flights are not booked with a passport - but on a *name*. They cannot be used by someone else (= having a different name).
On your outbound leg, you will need to use either the passport that has the matching name, or the US passport together with documentation of the name change. The gate agent will probably also ask you about your return leg, as they are required to check that you can enter the US again. Although your US passport ensures that, the names don't match, which again requires documentation of the change.
Either leg, you will need this name-change documentation, or convince the gate agent that having two passports with two different names is perfectly legal and fine (that might be easy or not)

Comment: Having different names in two passports is indeed very much legal and common.